# ¿Por qué da estos errores?

Tags: php

Tengo 2 errores, uno me dice que: **la variable creditos no está inicializada** y si lo está, otro en el `switch`

> **too many nested blocks in function declaration.**

Os dejo mi código.

La idea es que parto de 100 créditos y cada vez que juegue pago 10 y si sale uno de los números del `switch` pues gano créditos y debe de salir un mensaje con los créditos que he ganado

```
 <?php
        $creditos = 100;

        function partida() {
            if ($creditos > 9) {
                $fichas = 0;
                $creditos -= 10;
                $num1 = math . random_int(0, 9);
                $num2 = math . random_int(0, 9);
                $num3 = math . random_int(0, 9);
                $resultado = array($num1, $num2, $num3);
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($resultado); $i++) {
                    switch ($resultado[$i]) {
                        case 2:
                            $fichas += 25;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $fichas += 100;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            $fichas += 5;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    $creditos += $fichas;
                    $comentario = "has conseguidos $fichas de premio";
                } 
                }else{
                    $comentario ="no hay suficientes creditos";
                }
                echo $comentario;
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Hola por favor puedes colocar los errores tal y como te lo esta mandando php. Pero según puedo ver en tu código estas usando una función  a la cual no le estas pasando la variable creditos. Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es correcto, la variable `$creditos` está fuera de la función `partida()` es decir, a pesar que existe en el archivo, recuerda que una función es un bloque de código que no tiene relación con el demás código ( Aquí no es Javascript ). Entonces para resolverlo, debes pasar la variable `$creditos` al momento de invocar la función

```
$creditos = 100;

function partida( $creditos ) {
  $nuevos_creditos = $creditos;
  // Todo tu código
}

partida( $creditos );
```

Te recomiendo que lo hagas así, existe la forma de hacer tus variables de scope global, pero sinceramente nadie lo recomienda. También te sugiero que crees una nueva variable que contenga lo que llegó como función, para que puedas manipularla a tu gusto.

Answer (score 2):

Aparte de lo dicho por @AlbertoSiurob en su respuesta. Puedes simplificar la función también, si te quieres ahorrar el bloque `switch`:

```
function partida( $creditos ) {
    if ($creditos > 9) {
        $fichas = 0;
        $creditos -= 10;
        $num1 = math . random_int(0, 9);
        $num2 = math . random_int(0, 9);
        $num3 = math . random_int(0, 9);
        $resultado = array($num1, $num2, $num3);

        #Guarda los premios por cada case
        $premios=array(2=>25, 3=>100, 5=>5);
        foreach ($resultado as $v) {
            #Si se encuentra el índice, se suma el premio a fichas
            $fichas+=isset($premios[$v]) ? $premios[$v] : 0;
        }
        $creditos += $fichas;
        $comentario = "has conseguidos $fichas de premio";
    } else {
        $comentario ="no hay suficientes creditos";
    }
    echo $comentario;
    return $creditos;
}
```

Simplemente se crea un array con los premios `$premios=array(2=>25, 3=>100, 5=>5);` y se aumenta el valor si se encuentra el índice dentro del `foreach`. Esto hace el código más portable, porque en caso de querer agregar un nuevo `case` sólo lo asignas como valor del array asociativo. Imaginemos que en un futuro haya un `case 1`, que recibirá 7 fichas, sólo hay que agregar esto y nada más:  `$premios=array(1=>7, 2=>25, 3=>100, 5=>5);`

Otra cosa interesante sería agregar un `return`$creditos` a la función, para saber luego de su llamada cuál es el valor actual de los créditos. Así, se hace una asignación a la llamada a la función:

```
$creditos = 100;
$newCredits=partida( $creditos );
echo "\nNuevo valor: $newCredits";
```